# Reduce bundle size of lodash

Tags: webpack-bundle-analyzer

Is this correct to create a file in which I'll put all imports?

```
// lodash-helper.js
export const isEqual = import('lodash/isEqual');
export const includes = import ('lodash/includes');
export const filter = import ('lodash/filter');

// some-file.component.ts
import { isEqual } from 'src/core/helpers/lodash-helper'; // In this file I need only one import
```